# Java WS file upload service

Tags: soap, wsdl, wsdl2java, java-ws

I am currently working on a Java Web Service project. It is deployed on an Apache Tomcat 7 server and I need to provide a service for uploading files to the server. Also, the web service should be available to systems that may not use java. Thus, I need to make my web service universally available for all clients (i.e. C#, php etc.).
After browsing the web, I have found many solutions, but none of them does not explain how can I fulfill the aforementioned criteria. To be more specific, I have come across MTOM and Java WS Annotations that are referenced to be essential in order to specify universally accepted data stuctures, such as Java's DataHandler.
Let me post a sample code of my web service:

```
public class DataFileServer extends AbstractFileServer {

    private int _buffer_size;

    public DataFileServer() {
        _buffer_size = 100000;
    }

    public DataFileServer(int bufferSize) {
        _buffer_size = bufferSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void uploadFile(String AbsoluteFilePath, FileObject FileInfo) {
        DataHandler _handler = FileInfo.getHandler();
        try {
            InputStream is = _handler.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File(AbsoluteFilePath + 
                "/" + FileInfo.getName() + "." + 
                FileInfo.getType()));
            byte[] b = new byte[_buffer_size];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while((bytesRead = is.read()) != -1) {
                os.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The DataFileServer is the class that will to the upload operation, and the Web Service interface will be as follows:

```
@WebService()
public class ETL_WS {

    private DataHandler _handler;
    private String server_dir = "/home/user/Desktop/FileServer";

    public int fileUpload(String FileName, DataHandler CsvFile) {
        FileObject _file = new FileObject(FileName, CsvFile);
        _handler.uploadFile(this.server_dir, _file);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

My question is, how am I going to ensure that the DataHandler object provided to my web service is going to be of the right type. Also, can I improve the security and the performance of the file upload operation with any way?

Thank you